# How is setTimeout called in a for loop js?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I am trying to write a for loop that has a delay between running each iteration. I thought Id go about it by using `setTimeout()` as follows.

Input:

```
for (let i=0;i<3;i++){
  setTimeout(()=>{console.log("hi")},10000)
}
```

Output:

```
hi
hi
hi
```

What seems to be happening is that its waiting 10 seconds and then runs the entire for loop, rather than waiting 10 seconds to run each iteration of the for loop. After the first `hi` is shown to the console, the other 2 follow instantaneously. Why is this the case, rather than a delayed logging of `hi` and how can I go about doing this?

Comment: Maybe the `setInterval` function is what you want?

Comment: `setInterval` has the same problem

Comment: Use `(i + 1) * 10000` as the timeout.

Comment: @V.Jain TLDR; wrap the setTimeout promise which resolves when the setTimeout executes then await on the promise

Comment: This is because the loop runs immediately (runs 3 times) not waiting for setTimeout to finish executing. Hence the three setTimeout execute after each other after 10...

Answer (score 4):

You don't call `setTimeout()` inside a for loop. You replace the for loop with `setTimeout()`:

```
let loop = 0;
function loop () {
    console.log("hi");
    x++;

    if (x<3) {
        setTimeout(loop, 10000);
    }
}
loop();
```

This is the traditional way of doing it. You can use a Promise with `async`/`await` in modern js to use the for loop again:

```
// First we need a promisified setTimeout:
function delay (ms) {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => setTimeout(resolve,ms));
}

async function test () {
    for (let i=0;i<3;i++){
        await delay(10000);
        console.log("hi");
    }
}

test();
```

Comment: @V.Jain maybe because this solution is already covered in the flagged duplicate

Comment: Even if thats true, I thought you downvote incorrect or misleading answers? I just wanted to know what about these answers are incorrect/misleading.

Comment: Works very well.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is asynchronous which means your timers start immediately rather than each timer blocking until done, and they all execute after roughly 10s plus a few ticks.

If you want you can try setInterval with a counter to clear it:

```
var counter = 0;
var interval = setInterval(function(){
   console.log("hi");
   counter+=1;
   if (counter == 3) { clearInterval(interval); }
}, 10000);
```

You can probably work out an alternative using setTimeout as well.